# SQLException like archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-00257

can any one give me an idea regarding this below error:

```
2011-02-11 05:48:42,858 
  -[c=STATS_VITALS] Error running system monitor for connectionCloseTime: 
  java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: archiver error. 
  Connect internal only, until freed.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: archiver error. 
  Connect internal only, until freed.
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually occurs when the system encounters an error while trying to archive a redo log.  Was this working previously and it just failed now for the first time, or is this a new installation? Do you know where your logs are being archived? If so, check to see if that location is out of space as a first step.  Once you have more information we might be able to help you a little more effectively.

Comment: Not new installation.Previously i got same issue, I deleted logs and start working again i got same exception.So much space is there under log file location..

Comment: Can you take a look at the alert.log file and see what was recorded when this error happened? If you don't know where it is you can run the following query: select value from v$parameter where name = 'background_dump_dest';

Comment: I met this because out of disk space.